# XPATH to verify the existence of a text in the html

Tags: xpath, selenium

How can I check if the text I'm looking for exists in this html ?

```
<ul>
   <li class="texto">
      Warning, invalid login. The login <b> rafael1983 </ b> is already associated with a registered user.
   </li>
</ul>
```

I'm doing this xpath expression to retrieve the text:

```
//*[contains(child::text(), 'Warning, invalid login. The login rafael1983 is already associated with a registered user.')]
```

however the "rafael1983" is within the `<b>` tag, so that expression does not work, anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
//*[contains(normalize-space(.), 'Warning, invalid login. The login rafael1983 is already associated with a registered user.')]
```

or:

```
//li[contains(normalize-space(.), 'Warning, invalid login. The login rafael1983 is already associated with a registered user.')]
```

depending on exactly which element you want to match.

It seems a bit strange to me that you want to check for that specific string, including the login name - I would expect that you are interested in ANY 'Invalid login' message.

Comment: is because the system I'm developing can give various error messages on the same screen i have to check each one.

thank you !

Comment: This works because "." means "the string value of the node", which combines all the child nodes to create the value.  Thus it doesn't care that some of the text is inside `<b>...</b>` and some is not.